# Différence entre l'origine des mots terminant en « -aison » et « -ation »

Tags: étymologie, noms, latin, lexique

Cf. *terminaison*, *pendaison*, *raison*, *saison*, *comparaison*, *maison*

Pour autant que je sache, ces mots sont tous issus d'une transformation de la terminaison latine « *-atiō* », comme par exemple *ratiō* > *raison*, *satiō* > *saison*. Cependant, il y a aussi beaucoup d'autres mots qui trouvent leurs racines dans des mots latins terminant en *-atiō*, sans subir la même transformation, comme par exemple *declaratiō* > *déclaration* et non *déclaraison*.

Pourquoi existe-t-il deux transformations divergentes ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ces deux transformations ne sont pas divergentes. L'une (-aison) est de source populaire, L'autre (-ation) est d'origine savante et postérieure à la première.

De fait, ce suffixe latin (*ationem*) est d'abord entré dans notre langue par la voie populaire sous la forme *-aison* (cuvaison, ventaison, floraison, venaison...) avant d'entrer par la voie savante sous la forme *-ation* (activation, aération, ordination, formation...)

Le DHLF observe que la formation de nouveaux dérivés en *-aison* stoppe dès le XVIe siècle à partir duquel seule la terminaison savante sera retenue.
Certains mots populaires sont même oubliés au profit de leur équivalent savant (*dérivaison -> dérivation* ; *formaison -> formation*...)

EDIT : Comme c'est d'ordinaire avec des mots différents issus de la même étymologie, ceux qui ont le même sens s'alignent sur une seule orthographe, ceux qui ont des sens différents continuent leur vie en toute indépendance sous leur orthographe d'origine. On parle alors, comme l'observe @jlliagre ci-contre, de doublets étymologiques comme, par exemple, pour ce suffixe, *inclinaison* / *inclination*...

Comment: Sentez-vous libre d'inclure le lien et la citation de ma réponse, suite à quoi je l'effacerai. Inutile d'avoir deux réponses déclarant la même chose.

Comment: @Montéedelait : Merci pour cette offre. Maintenant... moi et le bricolage de forme cela fait deux. Je m'en voudrais en tous les cas de contribuer ainsi à la suppression d'une autre contribution. Et ce d'autant que les deux côte à côte apportent une information... cachée et peut-être inattendue... : Le DHLF a pompé sur le TLF! ;)

Comment: Ainsi soit-il. Je suppose que votre commentaire aidera sans doute les gens à voir cet aspect caché de l'information fournie, qui m'avait quant à moi échappé.

Comment: On pourrait aussi évoquer les rares doublets comme *inclination* / *inclinaison* et *défloration* / *défloraison*.

Answer (score 3):

Selon le TLFi, à l'article [-tion](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-tion) :

> *-aison* et *-ation*. Le suffixe *-ationem* est entré en français par la voie populaire *(oraison, venaison)*, puis par la voie savante *(formation, ordination, signification)*. Dès le XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle, *-aison* cesse de former de nouveaux dérivés et les formations populaires en *-aison* sont remplacées par des formations savantes en *-ation : °altéraison/altération, °dérivaison/dérivation, formaison/formation*

Ça n’explique certes pas tout, mais c’est un début d’explication.